# WPF Binding not updating even though PropertyChanged fires

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a view model that I bind to my view via

```
        public MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
```

MyViewModel implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface with the standard

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

MyViewModel has a string member called Status which is defined with

```
        private string _status = string.Empty;

        public string Status
        {
            get => _status;

            set
            {
                if (_status != value)
                {
                    _status = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

The Status property is used in my view like so:

```
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"></TextBlock>
```

As my application runs, the value of Status periodically changes. I can see that OnPropertyChanged fires correctly in each case, however the view only changes *some of the time*. I have also noticed (by logging to the console when a property changes) that the property sometimes changes (and fires the change event) but then takes a few seconds before the View updates randomly.

I believe this has something to do with the binding. I can't afford to manually trigger a bindingExpression.UpdateTarget() manually, as the property changes when certain things happen under the hood of the view model (outside of the influence of the view).

I expected the view to update as soon as the binded property changed, but it did not.

I have tried changing the binding mode to TwoWay as well as binding the View Model within the XAML but nothing changes. There must be something I am missing. Appreciate any help.

Comment: i think you need to set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged if you are trying to update property from view model

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz That's wrong. UpdateSourceTrigger has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event. It controls how TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings update the source property of a Binding when the target property has changed.

Comment: My mistake, I think this will resolve your issue:-  Set Mode=TwoWay <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>

Comment: "*the value of Status periodically changes*" how exactly? Show us the relevant parts of your code. Also explain why you have two methods that invoke the PropertyChanged event. Both do the same thing, why??

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz That doesn't make sense, seriously. It's a TextBlock, not a TextBox where you edit text.

Comment: @Clemens When I want to update the Status inside the viewModel, I just change it like : `Status = "Moving Rack";`

Comment: Are you doing to much work on the UI thread? Is that causing a delay in event propagation?

Comment: you have to post complete code of your ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Daniel all you are showing here is just working. You don't have to show us your complete code, but the relevant parts that would enable us to reproduce your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @Brannon this may be it, I have a separate task running on a different thread that consumes a lot of the CPU. I will look at this next. thanks